# Trigger Unknown column 'OLD' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create trigger on table `UsefulResources`.

The trigger code looks like this:

```
create trigger TBD_UsefulResources before delete
on UsefulResources for each row
begin
    Update SystemCycle set CurrentCycle=CurrentCycle+1;

    INSERT INTO DeletedPhysically (TableName, PKName, PKValue, DelAtRowCycle, RowCycle, Created)
    VALUES ("UsefulResources", "Ufr_GUID", OLD.Ufr_GUID, (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), now());
end;
```

However I'm getting the following error if I want to execute it via mysql client:

```
mysql> create trigger TBD_UsefulResources before delete
    -> on UsefulResources for each row
    -> begin
    ->     Update SystemCycle set CurrentCycle=CurrentCycle+1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
mysql>
mysql>     INSERT INTO DeletedPhysically (TableName, PKName, PKValue, DelAtRowCycle, RowCycle, Created)
    ->     VALUES ("UsefulResources", "Ufr_GUID", OLD.Ufr_GUID, (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), now());
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'OLD.Ufr_GUID' in 'field list'
mysql> end;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1
mysql>
```

When I execute that create trigger trough my client which is not checking sql syntax before execution it works fine on the server.

Any idea?

Comment: IF you execute in the command line you need to specify the delimiter `DELIMITER //` before and at the end `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Post your table structure of UsefulResources table

Comment: @Mihai thanks a lot, works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mihai

code like this solves the problem. We need to change end line delimiters to stop execution command on each ";".  That's a client problem only. When I was executing the code block via `mysql.query(query)` it worked because the system treats the whole query as one thing.

So the correct code should look like:

```
delimiter //

create trigger TBD_UsefulResources before delete
on UsefulResources for each row
begin
    Update SystemCycle set CurrentCycle=CurrentCycle+1;

    INSERT INTO DeletedPhysically (TableName, PKName, PKValue, DelAtRowCycle, RowCycle, Created)
    VALUES ("UsefulResources", "Ufr_GUID", OLD.Ufr_GUID, (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), (Select CurrentCycle From `SystemCycle` where Syc_ID=1), now());
end;
//

delimiter ;
```